# Comparing to multiple values using |

Tags: javascript

```
  var newArr = arr.filter(function(val){
    return val != false|null|0|""|undefined|NaN;})
```

I'm trying to filter our values that equal false, null, 0, "", undefined, NaN.
The code above seems to work for false, 0, and "" and I'm not sure if I'm writing null, undefined and NaN incorrectly or if the code is not supposed to work at all.
Please let me know if this is just wishful thinking

Comment: use || for logical or, | is for bitwise or

Comment: Syntax like this is definitely not possible in JavaScript. You may want to put the candidate values in an array and use indexOf() to see if there are any matches instead.

Comment: @JaromandaX That is not the problem.

Comment: it is still **a** problem - if I thought it were **the** problem I would've posted an **answer** rather than a **comment**

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to achieve that by just returning the value itself (if you double "negate" you get a boolean)

```
var newArr = arr.filter(function(val){ return !!val })
```

That's possible because all of those values are "considered `false`" in javascript

If you want to clearly show all the options, then the easiest way is to use an `&&` (AND) operator.

```
val !== false && val !== null && val !== 0
```

and so on... (or as mentioned by Jeremy Banks, use an Array together with indexOf)